# ORA-01017 invalid username/password as default role oracle developer

Tags: .net, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

So, I am trying to make a connection to an oracle database through oracle developer but I am constantly getting invalid username/password. I was given a tnsnames.ora file to connect with. I tried using a basic connection with information I physically read from that tnsname file and I tried connecting with the TNS connection. With both I used the default role since the sysdba gave me the .ora file.   With the tns connection, the network alias shows up. I think the connection is made and it has to due to with username/password. I am wondering if there can be issues with ORA-01017 that are in no relation to the username/password that I can troubleshoot before asking again if the username/password given to me was incorrect.

Comment: Many DBAs install the sample schema, scott (with password tiger).  Have you tried that?

Comment: try if you can do tnsping .. if that work fine then it is probably issue with your username/password ..

Comment: No luck patrick, and I will read into tnsping.

Comment: I was just able to do tsping with the host name in cmd line and it connected ok! But I connected using a sqlnet.ora file from a different path compared to the one I use for my oracle database connection if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

No.  An ORA-01017 always indicates an invalid username & password, just as the error message indicates.

Now, of course, it is possible that you've been given the connection information for the wrong database such that the username & password are correct, just for a different database.  But as far as the database you're connecting to is concerned, you'd still have an invalid username or password.

Comment: if you're logging in as SYS, you need to set the AS SYSDBA role in the connection properties. But i doubt that's what is happening. The DBA also gave you a username/password to login with?

Comment: Yes, and my account was just locked for too many log-in attempts. Does that mean I am connecting to database and just wrong information?